# How to map child items using glass mapper 5.8?

Tags: sitecore-api, glass-mapper, datasource

I want to map child items which come from a parent data source and I gave the parent datasource as the datasource for the rendering.

This is my Datasource in my rendering
[image: DataSource Image]

This is my list of child items under my datasource

[image: Child Content]

Now I want to map the child items using Glassmapper. How to do that?

Here is my Controller code

[image]

Here are my Models

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of your view file code

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method to retrieve the child items is to use the children attribute:

```
public class Home
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

If all children are one type then you can use:

```
public class Home
{
    [SitecoreChildren]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }

    [SitecoreChildren]
    public virtual IEnumerable<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

Product and News are example of types of children.

Comment: Its not working Himmat

Comment: Can someone please share a demo code?

Answer (score 1):

I used this code and it is working for me. Please try this.

This is the main class

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "youritemtemplate", EnforceTemplate = SitecoreEnforceTemplate.Template)]
public class FilterGroup : GlassBase
{
    [SitecoreField("Name")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [SitecoreChildren (InferType = true, IsLazy = false)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<FilterOption> FilterOptions { get; set; }
}
```

This is child class

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "youritemtemplate", EnforceTemplate = SitecoreEnforceTemplate.Template)]
public class FilterOption : GlassBase
{
    [SitecoreField("Name")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Thanks